# Find the expansion of $\frac {1}{z^2+3}$ valid for $|z-1|<2$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Find the expansion of  $$\frac {1}{z^2+3}$$ valid for $|z-1|<2$.

Should I start with considering $z-1=u$ ? It gets messy that way. I tried reorganizing the denominator of $f(z)$ but that didn't work too.

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition. After that it becomes routine.

Comment: but in this type where denominator has power 2 usually the expansion is direct ?

Comment: Only if you expand with the centre $0$, but here you're asked to take $1$ as the centre. $z^2+3 = ((z-1)+1)^2+3 = (z-1)^2 + 2(z-1) + 4$, and that doesn't expand nice directly.

Comment: @DanielFischer For partial fractions to work there there should be more terms in the denominator. no ? I dont fully what you are suggesting. Should i write it like $z^2-({\sqrt{3}i})^2$ and then proceed with partial fraction decomposition ?

Comment: Yes, $$\frac{1}{z^2+3} = \frac{1}{(z-i\sqrt{3})(z+i\sqrt{3})} = \frac{1}{2i\sqrt{3}}\left(\frac{1}{z-i\sqrt{3}} - \frac{1}{z+i\sqrt{3}}\right).$$

Comment: @DanielFischer now just expand ?  no need to substitute like $z-1=u$ ?

Comment: Of course you need to write $\frac{1}{z-a} = \frac{1}{(z-1)-(a-1)}$ to get an expansion around $1$. In this special case, you have a shortcut, as illustrated in mike's answer, since - with $v = \frac{u}{2}$ - you have $$\frac{1}{1+v+v^2} = \frac{1-v}{1-v^3},$$ where you can expand $\frac{1}{1-v^3}$ into a geometric series. But you only sometimes have such a shortcut, the partial fraction decomposition always works.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, This was a new question i learnt. Please post it as an answer so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Because $|z-1|<1<2$, you can just consider that $u=z-1$ is a small variable, $|u|<1$.

$$\frac{1}{z^2+3} = \frac{1}{(z-1)^2 + 2(z-1) + 4}=\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{1+u/2+u^2/4}$$

Mathematica 7.0 showed that

$$\frac{1}{u^2/4 + u/2 + 1}=\left(1-\frac{u}{2}\right)\sum_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)^{3k}$$

This leads us to write ($v=u/2$),

$$\frac{1}{1+v+v^2}=\frac{1-v}{1-v^3}=(1-v)\sum_0^{\infty}v^{3k}$$

This also converges for $|v|<1$ (i.e.,$|z-1|<2$).

mike